# How to infinite Loop jQuery gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, jsfiddle

I have created an image slideshow using jQuery where 5 images appear one after another during an interval of 25 seconds. Each images stays on for 5 seconds before fading out and then the next image fades in.
The slideshow works fine but I want it to **loop forever**,  *i.e.* after the **last** image fades out, it should ***restart* the animation from the first image**.
I tried using `setInterval` but couldn't succeed. Here's the working example of the slideshow which I've coded:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdRTR/88/)

Here's the complete code:

**HTML:**

```
<img id="img1" src="http://njballroomdancecenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1500x1000.jpg" style="display: block; width: 50%; position: absolute;" />
<img id="img2" src="http://njballroomdancecenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1500x1000-1.jpg" style="display: block; width: 50%; position: absolute;" />
<img id="img3" src="http://njballroomdancecenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1500x1000-2.jpg" style="display: block; width: 50%; position: absolute;" />
<img id="img4" src="http://njballroomdancecenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1500x1000-3.jpg" style="display: block; width: 50%; position: absolute;" />
<img id="img5" src="http://njballroomdancecenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1500x1000-4.jpg" style="display: block; width: 50%; position: absolute;" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img2,#img3,#img4,#img5").hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#img1").fadeOut("slow", function () {});
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#img2").fadeIn("slow", function () {});
    }, 5000);    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#img2").fadeOut("slow", function () {});
    }, 10000); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#img3").fadeIn("slow", function () {});
    }, 10000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#img3").fadeOut("slow", function () {});
    }, 15000); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#img4").fadeIn("slow", function () {});
    }, 15000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#img4").fadeOut("slow", function () {});
    }, 20000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#img5").fadeIn("slow", function () {});
    }, 20000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#img5").fadeOut("slow", function () {});
    }, 25000);
});
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping it in setInterval()? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: for christ's sake, They still have relevant information.  Just because they have a few mistakes doesn't mean they're a leper.

Comment: Roko, thats just your opinion (and a misinformed one at that). It is by no means a rule and by no means should you present it as one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function( $ ){             // DOM ready shorthand
    
    // ::: Fade Gallery: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18454450/383904
    var $gal = $("#gallery"),
        $img = $gal.find(">*"),
        n = $img.length,          // number of images
        c = 0,                    // counter
        itv;                      // loop interval       
   
    function anim(){ $img.fadeOut().eq( ++c % n ).stop().fadeIn(); }
    function loop(){ itv = setInterval(anim, 3000); }
    function stop(){ clearInterval( itv ); }
    
    $img.hide().eq(c).show();     // Begin with `c` indexed image
    $gal.hover( stop, loop );     // Pause gallery on hover
    loop();                       // START!
    
});
```

```css
#gallery     { position:relative; }
#gallery img { position:absolute; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(Hover to pause gallery)<br>
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x130/993/fff?text=1" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x130/379/fff?text=2" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x130/973/fff?text=3" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x130/739/fff?text=4" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x130/793/fff?text=5" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is exactly the sort of functionality which I wanted and this was the most simplest answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @Plymouth223 thanks! P.S: the `$(function(){ ..... });` is not that bulletproof against the use of the alias `$` from other libraries, but just inside a jQuery - only - environment.

Answer (score 2):

Do one loop in a function. Have the function call itself after a setTimeout. It should run forever. You would want some array logic though to loop through the pictures. Something like so:

```
function go(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#img'+i).fadeOut(5000);
    if (i<6) i=1;    
    else i++;
    go(i);
  },5000);
}
go(1);
```

Comment: +1 You could also spare additional lines checking for `i % images.length` (instead the `if else`)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this can be solved by standard javascript, and as ntgCleaner has suggested in the comments via the `setInterval(function, time)` function.

In pseudo code one could express this as such:

```
function wrapper() {
   allYourCode()
}

setInterval(wrapper, 90000) // running the function wrapper every 1,5 minute.
```

Answer (score 1):

I like runfaj's solution, but for completion, here's a setInterval(..) solution. Use setTimeout to properly synchronise when the setInterval timeout should execute. Example snippet [with a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmZsp/):

```
var singleImageDisplayTime = 5000;
var completeLoopTime = 5 * singleImageDisplayTime;

function fadeInFunction(jquerySelector) {
    $(jquerySelector).fadeIn("slow", function () {});
}
function fadeOutFunction(jquerySelector) {
    $(jquerySelector).fadeOut("slow", function () {});
}
...
setTimeout(function () {
    fadeInFunction("#img1");
    setInterval(function() { fadeInFunction("#img1"); }, completeLoopTime);
}, 5 * singleImageDisplayTime);
setTimeout(function () {
    fadeOutFunction("#img1");
    setInterval(function() { fadeOutFunction("#img1"); }, completeLoopTime);
}, 1 * singleImageDisplayTime);
...
```